# Is there a way to perform smart searches from a website?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am working in python. I gained a free trial access to a website called AdInsight. This is an example of how it is structured: [this](https://adisinsight.springer.com/drugs/800038287). Now the point is that the website is not free access but I had to request a free trial through my Institution so that when I try to scrape it using Bs4 or similar it appears something that looks to me as if I do not have the requirements to enter the web page (which I have since when I try t enter "normally" I manage to do. Maybe a concern could be that I am opening the webpage in chrome and working on a local envs in Safari.
However the bit of html code that seems to be relevant to me is the following:

```
</script>
  <script class="optanon-category-2" type="text/plain">
   dataLayer = [{
    'user': {
    'visitor_id': getVisitorIdFromLocalStorage()
    },
    'session': {
    'authentication':{
    'authenticationID': '1',
    'method': 'anonymous'
    }
    },
    'page': {
    'pageInfo': {},
    'category': {
    'pageType': ''
    },
    'attributes': {
    'template': '',
    }
    },
    'privacy': {},
    'version': '1.0.0',
    }];
    (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-N8RLKKZ');
    
    function getVisitorIdFromLocalStorage() {
    return localStorage.getItem("visitor_id");
    }
  </script>
  <noscript>
   <h1 class="noScriptMsg">
    Either you have JavaScript disabled or your browser does not support Javascript . To work properly, this page requires JavaScript to be enabled.
    <br/>
    <a href="https://www.enable-javascript.com/" target="_blank">
     How to enable JavaScript in your browser?
    </a>
   </h1>
  </noscript>
 </head>
 <body>
  <input id="userEmailId" name="userEmailId" type="hidden" value=""/>
  <input id="userBpIds" name="userBpIds" type="hidden" value="1"/>
  <input id="userIsLoggedIn" name="userIsLoggedIn" type="hidden" value="false"/>
  <input id="userIsLoginTypeInstitutional" name="userIsLoginTypeInstitutional" type="hidden" value="false"/>
  <input id="userIsAnonymous" name="userIsAnonymous" type="hidden" value="true"/>
  <input id="userIsAnonymousUser" name="userIsAnonymousUser" type="hidden" value="true"/>
```

Is there a way in which I can simply access the search engine of the website recursively and obtain a piece of info that I need' (which is hidden if you have no permissions)

Thank you,

Federico

Comment: The nature of this site is such that you have an understanding of what it is you're trying to do. You show us the code you used to accomplish it and it either doesn't work completely or not in the way you expected it to and then ask a question based on that. I would recommend looking for a search api provided by this site to run any search queries to get any info you're allowed to get from the site. I think it would be good to start there.

Comment: So, do I understand correctly that in order to access pages you want you need to sign in first?

Comment: @GProst thank you for the reply. So I work for an academic Institution that provided me a free trial with the website. I am performing remote access by home and already havee inputted the website credentials in Googlle Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC your scraping doesn't work cause you need to be signed in on that website.

Authentication in Web is done via cookies (sent via `Cookie` header in HTTP request), so in each of your HTTP request you should include that `Cookie`
header to be authenticated.

So, there are 2 common options I see:

1. Authenticate on the website manually in a browser, go to DevTools and copy `Cookie` header from Networking tab. Then set this header for the HTTP requests library you're using for scraping.
2. Use `Selenium` to sign in into the website and then scrape the website using `Selenium`

Another option is to check if that website has public API documentation. If they do then you should find all the needed info there, most likely there will be some auth token that you can generate to be used as a header in your HTTP requests for authorization.